# How to solve a Knapsack problem with extra constraints? (Or alternative algorithms)

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, matching, knapsack-problem

Expanding upon a common dynamic programming solution for the knapsack problem:

```
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
    results = []
    K = [[0 for x in range(W + 1)] for x in range(n + 1)]
    # Build tаble K[][] in bоttоm uр mаnner
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for w in range(W + 1):
            if (i == 0)  or  (w == 0):
                K[i][w] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= w:
                K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]], K[i-1][w])
            else:
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    print(K[n][W])
    return(set(results))


# Driver code
val = [60, 100, 120]
wt = [10, 20, 30]
W = 50
n = len(val)

knapSack(W, wt, val, n) = 220
```

Now perhaps I add extra constraints:

```
# Driver code
val_all = [60, 100, 120, 50, 80, 10]
wt_all = [10, 20, 30, 15, 20, 5]
W_all = 50
n_all = len(val_all)

val_1 = [60, 100, 120]
wt_1 = [10, 20, 30]
W_1 = 30
n_1 = len(val_1)

val_2 = [50, 80, 10]
wt_2 = [15, 20, 5]
W_2 = 25
n_2 = len(val_2)
```

I want to maximise all 3, using the same values. val_all has a solution of 240 [60, 100, 80]. val_1 is maxed at 160 [60, 100] and val_2 would max at 90 [80, 10] but given I want the same values and 10 does not sit in the other two sets the max solution would be 80.

I am also wondering if you can add to the function to give you the values chosen as well as the maximum value. And is this approach feasible for large lists as I have a list of 150,000 different values each with different weights.

There may be a better algorithm, my problem is I have 150,000 values each with a weight and need to select any number of those values such that we get a close to a ceiling W value. However, the data is actually a mixture of two different types of values and the sum of weights of each type also have a W1 and W2 ceiling value. I'd like to maximise all three equations but using the same set of values. Any value chosen in W1 or W2 must exist in W.

This knapsack code won't be very useful as I have 150k values with an average weight of 50 and a weight ceiling of 6mil. The time complexity given such large loops will be huge.

Comment: Don't understand the problem, but a knapsack problem with additional constraints are easily solved using a MIP model.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the top comment I found a package that is very fast and allows for this:

```
from mip import Model, xsum, maximize, BINARY

all = pd.read_csv('df_all.csv')
X = pd.read_csv('df_x_only.csv')
Y = pd.read_csv('df_y_only.csv')

p = all.id.values # as we arent optimizing the value of the index, p is irrelevant and we replace xsum(p[i] with xsum(w[i] in the objective function
w = all.new_weights.values
w1 = X.new_weights.values
w2 = Y.new_weights.values

c = 5876834
Cx = 4902953
Cy = 719051.4

I = range(len(w))
I1 = range(len(w1))
I2 = range(len(w2))

m = Model("knapsack")

x = [m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in I]

m.objective = maximize(xsum(w[i] * x[i] for i in I)) + maximize(xsum(w1[i] * x[i] for i in I1)) + maximize(xsum(w2[i] * x[i] for i in I2))

m += xsum(w[i] * x[i] for i in I) <= c*1.05
m += xsum(w[i] * x[i] for i in I) >= c*0.95
m += xsum(w1[i] * x[i] for i in I1) <= Cx*1.05
m += xsum(w1[i] * x[i] for i in I1) >= Cx*0.95
m += xsum(w2[i] * x[i] for i in I2) <= Cy*1.05
m += xsum(w2[i] * x[i] for i in I2) >= Cy*0.95

m.optimize()


selected = [i for i in I if x[i].x >= 0.99]
```